# C++ read line by line and output each lines

Tags: c++, io

Lets say I have a text file, and the text file contains the following:

hello world 
Welcome to C++

How would I print line by line from my .txt file? For example, this is part of my code

```
while (getline(input, document))
{
    if (!document.empty())
    {
        if (lineisthere(document)) {
            cout << "The word" << // << "is there" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "The word" << // << "is not there" << endl;
        }
        line++;
    }
}
input.close(); //closes the input
```

I want my output to look something like this:

The word *Hello Word* is there 
However, the word *Welcome to C++* is not there

Comment: I really have no idea what is being asked here. How is "Hello world" different from "Welcome to C++"? How is the function `lineisthere` supposed to tell the different between what 'is there' and what 'is not there'. I want to help because you're the first person in ages I've seen using `getline` correctly, but if I don't understand I can't help.

Comment: it just checks if hello world is in the first line , and also checks Welcome to C++ is in the second line. Greg answered exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad he answered for you. I still have no idea what you were asking or how his answer relates to it. Greg is obviously a cleverer man than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to use `document` where you have indicated `//`:

```
cout << "The word " << document << " is there" << endl;
```

Comment: it's a little harder to say what's not there, you have to know what's supposed to be on each line.

Comment: @Dave: Presumably the `lineisthere()` function performs that task somehow.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill ...And takes `document` by reference and fills it in with the correct possibly non existent line? I suppose we could make that assumption. And has some static line counter to know what line it's testing

Comment: @Dave: I'm not sure where you're going with that. There's a `getline()` in there that presumably reads a line from the input file.

Comment: Well I was thinking he wanted to be able to remove one of his lines and have his output tell him it was missing. The getline can't read a line that's not there, to tell you that it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string text;
  ifstream ifs("hello.txt");


    while(!ifs.eof()) 
    {
      getline(ifs,text);
      cout << "" << text << "\n" ;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is printing text file line by line:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string filename;
ifstream file;
    cout<<"enter file name";
    getline(cin,filename);
     filename.append(".txt");
    file.open(filename.c_str());


    string text;
    while(getline(file,text))
    {
        cout<<text<<endl;
    }
file.close();

    return 0;
}
```